# Multiple string arguments in Python print function

Tags: python, list

```
print('Hello''World')
>>> HelloWorld
```

How come this works, when multiple string arguments are not separated by comma?
I found this unusual because, like any other function multiple parameters must be separated with commas.
There should have been a syntax error.

Comment: There are more than two ways of writing string literals in your code: `'Hello'` and `"Hello"` are two examples. Since you can use the `'` character as a delimiter, then you can have: `'Hello"World'`. Except your formatting was off in your question and I mistook your `''` for `"`.

Comment: Python concatenates strings directly written behind each other. Just try `'Hello''World'` in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: [*"Multiple adjacent string or bytes literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation."*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)

Comment: Many languages concatenate string literals in this way. It's useful when you want a very long string but don't want your lines to be very long.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, adjacent string literals are concatenated by default.

```py
s = 'Hello'  "world"    '''!'''      """?"""
```

This is perfectly fine. I used different quotes for each literal, and even separate them with spaces, and everything is still fine.

Comment: Thanks, for answering...Can I surmise that, since adjacent string literals are concatenated by default, it is effectively a single parameter, hence absence of a comma doesn't produce an error.

Comment: @ParthasarathiBanerjee You are absolutely correct. If curious, you can consult the link on the comment above for more information.